# Nging redirect http and https to https://domain (without www)

Tags: redirect, nginx

This is my Nginx config:

```
upstream app_server {
  # Bindings to the Gunicorn server
  server 127.0.0.1:8002 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name "~^www\.(.*)$";
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  access_log path_to_nginx-access.log;
  error_log path_to_nginx-error.log;

  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name _;
  ssl_certificate path_to_nginx.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key path_to_nginx.key;

  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 5;
  root path_to_root;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
      proxy_pass http://app_server;
      break;
    }
  }
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  location = /500.html {
    root path_to_templates;
  }
}
```

My goal is to have all this addresses redirecting to https://domain.com

- http://domain.com
- https://domain.com
- http://www.domain.com
- https://www.domain.com

What should I change? 
Keep in mind that I need to handle multiple domains with the same Nginx server (vide server_name).

Thanks!